# Efficient way of matching linear data with grouped data

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Example.

I have two sets of data. Let's call them linear_data and grouped_data

linear_data is like `1 - 1, 1 - 2, 1 - 3, 2 - 3, 2 - 4, 3 - 6`. (Note: notation used for representation purpose is like Order ID  "-" Product ID)

I have to match this data with grouped_data which contains rules like
`{1 - 1,2,3}, {2 - 3,4}` (Note: notation used for representation purpose is like Rule ID  "-" Ordered List of Product IDs)

The rule will have up to maximum 4 values in it. It may happen that some product IDs doesn't have any rule associated with them. For eg. Here Product ID 6 don't any rule associated with it.

I want to match this two data set and retrieve fully matched rule set.

My current implementation is like

```
new_data = group linear_data by Order ID
iterate over new_data
permuted_data = create permutation of all Product Id in current Order


matched_rules = {}
for each permuted_data
   for each group_data
      if match 
         matched_rules.add(group_data.Rule_Id)
      end
   end  
end
```

Is this approach efficient way to implement this scenario? If not what algorithm will be best suited to solve this probelm?

Answer (score 1):

Create a map (hashmap, treemap) that maps all product ids to rules.
Map  myMap = new HashMap<>();
For example for example rules `{1 - 1,2,3}, {2 - 3,4}` the map looks like:

```
1 -> { 1 }
2 -> { 1 }
3 -> { 1, 2 }
4 -> { 2 }
```

and then for each record from linear_data, take it's productId, retrieve a set of rules from the map for this productId, and add retrieved set of rules to matchedRules

```
new_data = group linear_data by Order ID
iterate over new_data
for each record from linear_data {
    rules = get all rules from map by ProductId => just: rules = myMap.get( productId );
    matched_rules.addAll( rules )
}
```

**====== EDIT ==============**

If you want to find common rules that match all records, then use `Collection#retainAll` method => https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)

Just:

```
// create a set of all possible rules
Set<Intereg> allRules = new HashSet<>();
for( Integer ruleId: myRules.keys() ){
   allRules.addAll( myRules.get( ruleId ));
}

new_data = group linear_data by Order ID
iterate over new_data
for each record from linear_data {
    rules = get all rules from map by ProductId => just: rules = myMap.get( productId );
   // matched_rules.addAll( rules )
   allRules.retainAll( rules );
}
// At this point "allRules" contains only rules that match all processed records
```

Comment: This will return partial rule match too. If the linear_data contains ```1 - 1, 1 - 2``` then it will not fully match any rules and should not return any rules.

Comment: But thanks. I got the approach from your algorithm. Reverse mapping of rules will help in reduction of rules that needs to match